# Gulp task says task is finished before files are written

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat

I'm trying to automate a concat task with gulp 4. The problem is that the task finishes before the files are written. So when the concat task runs, it doesn't have any files to concatenate.

```
function criticalCssConcat (done){
  gulp.src('./user/themes/' + config.theme + '/assets/compiled/styles/critical/*.css')
  .pipe(concat('./user/themes/' + config.theme + '/assets/compiled/styles/main.critical.css'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
  done();
};

function criticalCss (done) {
  Object.keys(config.criticalCSSPath).forEach(function (obj) {
  critical.generate({
      src: config.criticalCSSPath[obj],
      width: 1920,
      height: 1080,
      dest: './user/themes/' + config.theme + '/assets/compiled/styles/critical/critical.' + obj + '.css'
  })
})
done();
};
```